# Selected sorting and display options within profile tabs are not highlighted

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

I can't tell the actual bug in the title,

[image]

[image]

Goto, any of your SE site and open your profile page, and click on the questions/answers/tags or any tab

Can you see the bug?

Comment: You mean the currently selected option is not getting highlighted?

Comment: These seem to work for me, I'm not sure what you're reporting?

Comment: @TimPost Previously, the currently selected sorting option would get highlighted. Thats not happening now.

Comment: Hmm, not sure if that's a bug, or if it has always been like that. The text to the left indicates what you've selected though.

Comment: @Bart I'm pretty sure it used to be highlighted. Certainly on the *votes* tab it was, and presumably it was consistent across the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for noticing.

It's fixed and it will be out in the next deployment.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the page source, there are some quote characters that have been accidentally escaped:

```html
<a href="/users/474189/duncan-jones?tab=activity&sort=comments" 
    class=&quot;youarehere&quot;>
```

This should be fixed to read:

```html
<a href="/users/474189/duncan-jones?tab=activity&sort=comments" 
    class="youarehere">
```

Testing this with FireBug confirms that the CSS highlighting works once this is corrected.